Giving C++ sole ownership of class object in pybind11
I have an application in which I want to expose a C++ class MyClass to python using pybind. Since I want python to be embedded within c++, I use PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE to expose my c++ class.
class MyClass
{
    void method1();
    void method2();
}

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(myModule, m)
{
    py::class_<MyClass>(m, "MyPyClass")
    .def(py::init())
    .def("method1()", &MyClass::method1)
    .def("method2()", &MyClass::method2)
}

Now, I want to it to work in such a way that I take an already instantiated instance of MyClass, say myInstance - and create the python instance from this. To achieve this, I use py::cast()
void doPython(MyClass* myInstance)
{
    py::module_ myModule = py::module_::import("myModule");

    py::object myPyInstance = py::cast(myInstance);

    ... // work with myPyInstance further
}

Now, the issue that I'm trying to solve is - I want my c++ application to have sole ownership of myInstance. I want myPyInstance to have nothing to do with the lifetime of myInstance. And that if myInstance is destructed at some point, myPyInstance should know about it and handle that case.
Is there some kind of weak ref workflow that I can use? pybind natively allows for unique_ptr or shared_ptr workflow, but none of those work for my case.
The custom smart pointer workflow sounds promising, and I pursued a solution where the smart pointer held a holder to myInstance. I hoped that .get() on the smart pointer would be called when the individual methods are called, allowing the smart pointer to check whether myInstance is alive or not. But it looks like .get() is called when cast() is called and the result is held onto.
There is return_value_policy::reference but it doesn't handle the case of the object being deleted by the c++ application while still being referenced by python, and this is a crucial case for me.
Perhaps py::capsule? but that turns out to be too verbose

My old answer to similar topic seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77042392/4165552 , but you would need to add some C++ functions (and expose them to python) to manipulate type-erased object. Otherwise I think struct MyClassWrapper { MyClass* ptr; }; should also do the job.

@pptaszni Thanks! Can you elaborate a bit on your proposed solutions? via that discussion that you linked, it seems like py::capsule is one way, but how exactly do you mean - just wrapping MyClass's methods in a py::capsule in a lambda while binding? And via MyClassWrapper, do you mean to bind MyClassWrapper to pybind instead of MyClass?

So, you can use MyClass* in Python as an opaque pointer, and then you need something like MyClass* getInstance(), void doSomethingWithTheInstance(MyClass*) functions that will be pythonized with py::capsue. Or you create MyClassWrapper, with some methods that internally operate on MyClass* ptr;, and you pythonize these methods from the wrapper in a classical way. The trick is to NOT tell python what your MyClass exactly is, if you want to keep it owned only by C++. Best solution depends on your "work with myPyInstance further".
